# Why container_layer is not getting added in the container_image?

Tags: docker, containers, bazel, bazel-rules

I have the following bazel definition:

`docker/project/BUILD.bazel`

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl", "container_image")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//docker/package_managers:download_pkgs.bzl", "download_pkgs")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//docker/package_managers:install_pkgs.bzl", "install_pkgs")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//docker/util:run.bzl", "container_run_and_commit")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl", "container_image", "container_layer")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

download_pkgs(
    name = "apt_pkgs_installables",
    image_tar = "@ubuntu_bionic_base_image//image",
    packages = [
        "build-essential",
        "libedit-dev",
        "libpq-dev",
        "libpython3.7",
        "libpython3.7-dev",
        "python",
        "python-dev",
        "python3.7",
        "python3-dev",
        "python3-pip",
        "python3-setuptools",
        "python3-venv",
        "python3-wheel",
    ],
)

install_pkgs(
    name = "apt_pkgs",
    image_tar = "@ubuntu_bionic_base_image//image",
    installables_tar = ":apt_pkgs_installables.tar",
    output_image_name = "apt_pkgs_image",
)

container_run_and_commit(
    name = "python3_extras",
    commands = [
        "ln -s /usr/share/doc/python3-venv /usr/bin/python3-venv",
        "ln -s --force /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python",
        "ln -s --force /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip",
        "pip install behave==1.2.6",
        "pip install kubernetes==21.7.0",
        "pip install polling==0.3.2",
        "pip install jinja2==3.0.3",
    ],
    image = ":apt_pkgs.tar",
)

container_image(
    name = "project-base",
    base = "@ubuntu_bionic_base_image//image",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    tars = [
        "python3_extras_commit.tar"
    ]
)

container_layer(
    name = "project-src",
    data_path = "//project",
    directory = "/opt/app/",
    files = [
        "//project",
    ],
    mode = "0o755",
)

container_image(
    name = "project",
    base = "@ubuntu_bionic_base_image//image",
    layers = [
        ":project-src"
    ],
    tars = [
        "python3_extras_commit.tar",
    ]
)
```

The project structure is:

```
.
├── BUILD.bazel
├── README.md
├── WORKSPACE
├── docker
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   └── project
│       └── BUILD.bazel
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── project
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── behave.ini
```

`project/BUILD.bazel` have a filegroup:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

filegroup(
    name = "project",
    srcs = [
        "Makefile",
        "behave.ini",
    ],
)
```

The expected output is to have the `Makefile` and `bahave.ini` files under `/opt/app/` declared in `project-src` `container_layer`, but the final docker image does not have these files.

```
bazel 4.0.0
```

Build command:

```
bazel build //docker/project:project --verbose_failures --sandbox_debug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the Bazel command should be:

```
bazel run //docker/project:project --verbose_failures --sandbox_debug
```

and `base` for `container_image` `project` should be `:python3_extras_commit.tar`

Answer (score 0):

`container_run_and_commit` produces a new image, so you don't need to create another image from it. The most direct way to fix this is removing `project-base` and use `python3_extras_commit.tar` wherever you're using it. Also, change the `base` for `project` to `python3_extras_commit.tar`:

```py
container_image(
    name = "project",
    base = ":python3_extras_commit.tar",
    layers = [
        ":project-src"
    ],
)
```

If you want the installed apt packages as a separate layer for some reason, use [container_run_and_commit_layer](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/docker/util/README.md#container_run_and_commit_layer) instead. Note that the result of that goes in `layers`, not `tars`. However, that will not have the apt packages from `download_pkgs` because those will be a separate layer, so you'll have to manage those separately if you go that route.

For reference, rules_docker has lots of good examples. [testing/examples/run_instruction_arbitrary/BUILD](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/f0e1eef6782a37fecc0a5dbc0a65e366e4e93e60/testing/examples/run_instruction_arbitrary/BUILD) shows most of these pieces.

Comment: Thanks Brain for answering it, the issue was with the bazel command, after I used `run` instead of `build` the files were getting included, however, the `base` also needs to be changed to include the `container_run_and_commit` layer.